# Python Noob issue with populating dictionary from file. Then updating dict and writing back to file

Tags: python, django, unix

The code below is supposed to lookup first column (key) from a file `Dict_file` and replace the first column of another file `fr`, with the value of the key found from `dict_file`. But it keeps the `dict_file` as an updated dictionary for future lookups.

Every time the code is run, it initializes a dictionary from that dict_file file. If it finds a new email address from another file, it adds it to the bottom of the dict_file.

It should work fine according to my understanding because if it doesn't find an @ symbol it assigns looking_for the value of "Dummy@dummy.com".. Dummy@dummy.com should be appended to the bottom of dict_file.

But for some reason, I keep getting new lines and blank lines appended along with other new emails at the end of the dict_file. I can't be writing blanks and newlines to the end of the dict_file.

Why is this happening? Whats wrong in the code below, my brain is about to explode! Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

d = {}
line_list=[]
alist=[]

f = open(sys.argv[3], 'r') # Map file

for line in f:
    alist = line.split()
    key = alist[0]
    value = alist[1]
    d[str(key)] = str(value)
    alist=[]
f.close()

fr = open(sys.argv[1], 'r') # source file

fw = open(sys.argv[2]+"/masked_"+sys.argv[1], 'w') # target file

for line in fr:
    columns = line.split("|")
    looking_for = columns[0] # this is what we need to search
    if looking_for in d:
        # by default, iterating over a dictionary will return keys
        if not looking_for.find("@"):
            looking_for == "Dummy@dummy.com"
            new_line = d[looking_for]+'|'+'|'.join(columns[1:])
            line_list.append(new_line)
        else:
            new_line = d[looking_for]+'|'+'|'.join(columns[1:])
            line_list.append(new_line)
    else:
        new_idx = str(len(d)+1)
        d[looking_for] = new_idx
        kv = open(sys.argv[3], 'a')
        kv.write("\n"+looking_for+" "+new_idx)
        kv.close()
        new_line = d[looking_for]+'|'+'|'.join(columns[1:])
        line_list.append(new_line)
fw.writelines(line_list)
```

Here is the dict_file:

```
WHATEmail@SIMPLE.COM    223
SamHugan@CR.COM 224
SAMASHER@CATSTATIN.COM  225
FAKEEMAIL@SLOW.com  226
SUPERMANN@MYMY.COM 227
```

Here is the fr file that gets the first column turned into the id from the dict_file lookup:

```
WHATEmail@SIMPLE.COM|12|1|GDSP
FAKEEMAIL@SLOW.com|13|7|GDFP
MICKY@FAT.COM|12|1|GDOP
SUPERMANN@MYMY.COM|132|1|GUIP
MONITOR|132|1|GUIP
    |132|1|GUIP
00 |12|34|GUILIGAN
```

Comment: Stab in the dark since I don't have your input files to look at, but try replacing `alist = line.split()` with `alist = line.strip().split()` and `columns = line.split('|')` with `columns = line.strip().split('|')`.

Comment: Python allows you to write the first part as `with open(sys.argv[3], 'r') as f: d.update(dict(line.split() for line in f))` :)

Comment: I added the dict_file as well as the fr file above. Please take a look.. Chaining the strip() method did not change the program result. I want to only store in dict_file if a new email address is found, only check is to see whether it contains "@" sign. If not, it should not be added to the dict_file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, you need to ignore blanks in your initial dictionary read, otherwise you will get an index out of range error when you run this script again. Do the same when you read via the fr object to avoid entering nulls. Wrap your email check condition further out for greater scope. Do a simple check for the "@" using the find method. And you're  good to go.

Try the below. This should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

d = {}
line_list=[]
alist=[]
f = open(sys.argv[3], 'r') # Persisted Dictionary File

for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    if line =="":
        continue
    alist = line.split()
    key = alist[0]
    value = alist[1]
    d[str(key)] = str(value)
    alist=[]
f.close()

fr = open(sys.argv[1], 'r') # source file
fw = open(sys.argv[2]+"/masked_"+sys.argv[1], 'w') # Target Directory Location

for line in fr:
    line = line.strip()
    if line == "":
        continue
    columns = line.strip().split('|')
    if columns[0].find("@") > 1:
        looking_for = columns[0] # this is what we need to search
    else:
        looking_for = "Dummy@dummy.com"
    if looking_for in d:
        # by default, iterating over a dictionary will return keys
            new_line = d[looking_for]+'|'+'|'.join(columns[1:])
            line_list.append(new_line)
    else:
        new_idx = str(len(d)+1)
        d[looking_for] = new_idx
        kv = open(sys.argv[3], 'a')
        kv.write(looking_for+" "+new_idx+'\n')
        kv.close()
        new_line = d[looking_for]+'|'+'|'.join(columns[1:])
        line_list.append(new_line)
fw.writelines(line_list)
```